# KnockoutJS not updating the ui after ko.applybinding

Tags: knockout.js

The html doesn't refresh after the ko.applybinding has been set. This only happens for my select-options objects.

```
    public ProjectleaderList: KnockoutObservableArray<string> = ko.observableArray([]);
    public AccountmanagerList: KnockoutObservableArray<string> = ko.observableArray([]);
    public OrganisationcontactList: KnockoutObservableArray<string> = ko.observableArray([]);

function(records) {
 let records = result.Records;
    switch (result.Message) {
        case "AccountManager":
            OrderPage.Instance().AccountmanagerList = ko.observableArray(records);
            OrderPage.Instance().Order.AccountManagerName = OrderPage.Instance().GetInitialListValue(OrderPage.Instance().Order.AccountManagerModelId, records);
            break;
        case "Organisationcontact":
            OrderPage.Instance().OrganisationcontactList = ko.observableArray(records);
            OrderPage.Instance().Order.OrganisationcontactName = OrderPage.Instance().GetInitialListValue(OrderPage.Instance().Order.OrganisationcontactModelId, records);

            break;
        case "Projectleader":
            OrderPage.Instance().ProjectleaderList = ko.observableArray( records);
            OrderPage.Instance().Order.ProjectLeaderName = OrderPage.Instance().GetInitialListValue(OrderPage.Instance().Order.ProjectLeaderModelId, records);
            break;
        default:
}           
    }
```

ViewModel:

```
    public ViewModel() {
    this.Order = OrderPage.Instance().Order;
    this.AccountmanagerList = OrderPage.Instance().AccountmanagerList;
    this.ProjectleaderList = OrderPage.Instance().ProjectleaderList;
    this.OrganisationcontactList = OrderPage.Instance().OrganisationcontactList;

}
```

If the server is fast enough the dropdown selects get filled, but if they occur after the ko.applybinding has happened the lists don't get populated. The arrays are seen in the 'Watch' as knockoutobservablearrays. So I have no clue what is happening.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks likely that you should be setting the value of the observable array rather than setting it to be a new instance of an observable array (on the assumption that it is intialised to an empty array when you first create your Instance).

e.g.

```
case "AccountManager":
            OrderPage.Instance().AccountmanagerList(records);
            OrderPage.Instance().Order.AccountManagerName = OrderPage.Instance().GetInitialListValue(OrderPage.Instance().Order.AccountManagerModelId, records);
            break;
```

On apply bindings, your lists will be bound to the original instance of the obs array - this won't change.

---

In reply to the comment - the documentation for this all is on the knockoutjs site (it's pretty comprehensive).

To expand a little on what is happening, imagine doing the same in a server side language:

```
class Foo {
   public Bar X { get; set;}
   ctor() {
     X = new Bar();
   }
}

var myFoo = new Foo();
var aBar = myFoo.X;
myFoo.X = new Bar();
bool match = aBar == myFoo.X; //False
```

You are binding to the initial instance of the observable array (i.e. the instance on the view model at the point in time when you call applyBindings).  If you change change the instance on the view model post that fact, the binding is not updated, but your front end remains bound to the initial instance of the observable array.

Comment: Wow, that did the trick. Can you point me to documentation for this particular thing? I couldn't find it. Thank you!